# TLS handshake flow

Tags: tls, sip

[image]
Hi I wanted to confirm if this is a valid handshake flow as i dont see any finish message.

Comment: Quoting from this [SO meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors): "Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly."

Comment: hi JAN if we click on the image it would expand i guess

Comment: No issues ! i will definitely take your feedback and make sure i post codes/messages directly instead of the screenshots. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Finished" message is sent after the "ChangeCipherSpec", which triggers the switch to the newly negotiated cryptographic parameters. Thus, it is encrypted, and shows up as "Encrypted Handshake Message" in the network dump.

Encryption hides all contents including the type of handshake message. What you can see from the outside is the message *length*, because encryption does not hide length, and also the "general type" (one in "handshake", "alert", "change cipher spec" and "application data"), because that type is recalled in the unencrypted record header. This is why the network dump can tell you that this is an encrypted *handshake* message — but it cannot tell you *which* message it is, since that's encrypted.